# Proof of limits whose denominators approach zero (using epsilon and delta)

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

!http://puu.sh/ycTIT/2cef434d88.png

For some reason, I always get stumped by the textbook because of their choice of epsilon and delta. I don't really understand what epsilon or delta to choose from when proving, let alone solving application questions. Could someone clarify that for me in this proof and in general? Like, why is epsilon1 derived from the lower bound of f(x) and then epsilon 2 derived from the upper bound of g(x)?... Shouldn't they be derived from the same bound?

Comment: Assuming positive numerator and denominator, to find a lower bound for a fraction, you want to use a lower bound for the numerator and an upper bound for the denominator.

Comment: For example, suppose $12 < a < 18$ and $2 < b < 3$. What are the lower and upper bounds for the fraction $a/b$? In other words, what is the smallest $a/b$ can be? And what is the largest $a/b$ can be?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure. I'm an idiot. What would the answer be?

Comment: Oh, the smallest a/b would be 4 and the largest would be 9.

Comment: Ah. So this is kinda making more sense to me. In a question like this how would we know which bound to select? Upper or Lower? And do you know why the textbook would assign such values to epsilon1 and M?

Comment: You're trying to prove the fraction approaches infinity. Hence you want to show for any choice of $M > 0$, the fraction can be made greater than $M$, for $x$ close enough to $c$ from above. Thus, you want a lower bound for the fraction. For $x$ close enough to $c$ from above, bound the numerator and denominator, and then, as in the numerical example which you correctly answered, choose the lower bound for the numerator and the upper bound for the denominator, and show that even being "generous", the fraction is still greater than $M$.

Comment: So if I'm not wrong, the lowerbound of numerator and upperbound of denominator is equal to lowerbound of the fraction? Could you pls answer the second part of my comment? And I really appreciate your replies at this time.

Comment: We want to make the fraction bigger than $M$. Since the numerator is getting close to $1$, it can't help much. To make sure it doesn't hurt, just take some simple lower bound (e.g., $1/2$) to keep it away from $0$. The denominator has to do work by getting small. Small enough so that the lower bound for the numerator over the upper bound for the denominator yields a result more than $M$. Given that forced the numerator to be more than $(1/2)$ what upper bound for the denominator would guarantee the fraction is more than $M$?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I think I'm starting to get this stuff. Is there anyway I can show my gratitude on this website?

Comment: If you wanna post an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer, but I appreciate the offer.